# Old tv-series about a missing boy talking to parents through his picture on milk box

Tags: story-identification, tv

I've seen this on TV in mid 00's, but the show might be older.

The plot I remember:

- A boy goes missing into some kind of alternate world
- There are some "garbage men" in white jumpsuits who collect trash and this boy hides from them
- In the real world he is put on milk carton box's "Missing kids" section and he somehow communicates to his parents through this box.

I've been told that this is *The Twilight Zone*, but I carefully watched 1985 and 2002 revivals and there was not this episode (or I missed an episode) and I doubt that 1950-1960's show would have been on TV in mid 00's.

So, the question is - if that is actually *The Twiligt Zone*, which revival/season/episode is that? If not, which show might that be?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This calls to mind an episode of *Eerie, Indiana* - "The Lost Hour", wherein the main character, Marshall Teller (in the series, all sorts of strange things happen in the namesake town and he and his friend Simon are two of the only people who pay enough attention to notice) somehow gets trapped in a version of the town empty except for a missing girl about his age, the sinister garbage men and an old milkman (who is hinted to be an older Marshall somehow). While he's trapped in this alternate world his face does show up on a milk carton.

Comment: Yep, exactly it is that episode. Thanks, it's been bugging me for a several years

Comment: Thanks, I was searching for this as well. When I was a kid I remember another show that had the same atmosphere: "Round The Twist".